# Configuring a dark theme for Angular Material

Tags: javascript, angularjs, material-design, angular-material

I'm working on a design for my webapp, and I'd like a dark theme similar to that seen [here](http://themes.getbootstrap.com/products/dashboard).

Sadly I've found the [Angular Material Theming Docs](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/Theming/03_configuring_a_theme) very hard to get my head around; no mention of where each colour will be used, how to set a background color or a text color etc.

I'm currently using:

```
.config(function($mdThemingProvider) {
    $mdThemingProvider.definePalette('coolpal', {"50":"#d9ddec","100":"#a6b1d2","200":"#8190bf","300":"#5468a5","400":"#495b90","500":"#252830","600":"#354168","700":"#2a3453","800":"#20283f","900":"#161b2b","A100":"#252830","A200":"#a6b1d2","A400":"#495b90","A700":"#2a3453"});
    $mdThemingProvider.definePalette('accentpal', {"50":"#ffffff","100":"#bfe7f7","200":"#8dd5f1","300":"#4ebee9","400":"#32b4e5","500":"#1ca8dd","600":"#1993c2","700":"#157fa7","800":"#126a8c","900":"#0e5570","A100":"#ffffff","A200":"#bfe7f7","A400":"#32b4e5","A700":"#157fa7"});
    $mdThemingProvider.definePalette('warnpal', {"50":"#f0fdf9","100":"#adf4dc","200":"#7bedc7","300":"#3ce5ac","400":"#21e1a0","500":"#1bc98e","600":"#17ae7b","700":"#149368","800":"#107855","900":"#0d5d42","A100":"#f0fdf9","A200":"#adf4dc","A400":"#21e1a0","A700":"#149368"});


    $mdThemingProvider.theme('default')
        .primaryPalette('coolpal').dark()
        .accentPalette('accentpal')
        .warnPalette('warnpal')
        .backgroundPalette('coolpal')
})
```

With a bit of hacking of colours this works ok, but if I look at the colors in an `md-toolbar`, the text is set to `rgba(0,0,0,0.87);` and I have no idea how to change it; I assumed it would come from somewhere in my `coolpal` theme, but it's not. Here's how my text elements are being styled:

[image: Angular Material mdthemingprovider example]

How can I alter `$mdThemingProvider` to ensure the text is a light color rather than opaque black?

Comment: Thanks for posting that. I was just prototyping something and didn't want to spend much time configuring colors. I wish there was a place with several different defined palettes for people to copy and paste for different themes.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest extending an existing palette, much easier.. such as;

```
var myPalette = $mdThemingProvider.extendPalette('indigo', {
            '500': '183863'
        });
$mdThemingProvider.definePalette('mine', myPalette);
$mdThemingProvider.theme('default')
            .primaryPalette('mine').dark();
```

Comment: But how do I know what elements are going to be affected by each colour change? It appears that text especially comes from nowhere in particular in your theme...

Comment: as far as I remember, for dark theme this just worked in my case, automagically reverting font color. you can go ahead and browse the css generated perhaps to see how darking works.